# Preprocessing Shuffling using multiple threads in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

1. There is a `python` list of image file names.
2. It is important that each image file is read and then following steps be applied on it - Taking 5 random crops and their mirror reflections.
3. In order to maintain randomness in the order of images fed to the CNN it is also important that all the images from preprocessing of one image should not go into the CNN together.

**My thoughts**

1. Let multiple CPU threads preprocess the images and put them in a random shuffle queue.
2. Let the `batchsize` number of images be dequeued from the queue and used for CNN.

**My questions**

a) Is the above way the most optimal way of working it out ?

b) Can anyone provide a `code example` which can be taken as a reference to work it out ?

Answer (score 0):

This is [my implementation](https://github.com/WeiTang114/tf-image-classification/blob/master/input.py) of what almost meets your requirements. The usage is easy in [train.py](https://github.com/WeiTang114/tf-image-classification/blob/ff790fcb1ab6062979688647bb078c2765ad0e7a/train.py).

```
dataset_train = Dataset("path/to/list.train.txt", subtract_mean=True, is_train=True, name='train')
dataset_val = Dataset("path/to/list.val.txt", subtract_mean=True, is_train=False, name='val')

dataset_train.shuffle()
for batch_x, batch_y in dataset_train.batches(batch_size):
    # batch_x: (batch_size, H, W, 3), batch_y: (batch_size)
    ...

# for samling for validation
for val_step, (val_batch_x, val_batch_y) in \
        enumerate(dataset_val.sample_batches(batch_size, 256)):
```

- Use "threading" and "concurrent.futures" for background loading, and "Queue" for a fixed size prefetch (but this doesn't use multi-CPU, decribed below, **without lost of speed**).
- Each image is random-cropped and flipped when loaded for training. (only center-cropped for testing and validation)
- A batch of images are dequeued for feeding to the CNN.

---

#### Why not use multi-CPU

Due to [GIL of CPython](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) python threads with [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) can't run simultaneously on multiple CPU cores. The alternative way to use multi-cores is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (mp).

[I used to implement the function](https://github.com/WeiTang114/tf-image-classification/blob/ff790fcb1ab6062979688647bb078c2765ad0e7a/input.py) with mp.Process and mp.Queue, but mp.Queue **VERY SLOW** for transferring large data like images between processes, because of the limitation of its implementation with [pipe()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (on Linux). The overhead is about 0.5 seconds for a batch of 100 256x256 images on a fast workstation where a batch of 64 images training of AlexNet only takes 0.6 sec.

I tried threading and Queue, and found that as the bottleneck is I/O but not CPU computation, and Queue.Queue transfer 100 images in no time, the loading becomes much faster even without multi-CPU.